# Unable to get the right Linux kernel headers to build a kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi3, header-files

I am trying to build a sample Linux kernel module using the following command in my makefile on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ running the latest Raspbian Buster OS updated with sudo apt-get dist-upgrade:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
```

I get the following output:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.57-v7+/build/ M=/home/pi/isr_test modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.19.57-v7+/build/: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

I tried installing linux headers using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.19.57-v7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.19.57-v7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.19.57-v7'
```

I tried looking for Linux headers using this command, and it looks like they are installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep kernel-headers
ii  raspberrypi-kernel-headers            1.20190718-1                          armhf        Header files for the Raspberry Pi Linux kernel
```

I tried looking in the /lib/modules directory:

```
ls /lib/modules
4.19.58+  4.19.58-v7+  4.19.58-v7l+
```

See how there's no 4.19.57 there?

Also, under /usr/src, all I have is these directories:

```
ls /usr/src
linux-headers-4.19.58+  linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+  linux-headers-4.19.58-v7l+  sense-hat
```

Again, nothing for 4.19.57.

For the current OS, here's what I get when I run uname -r:

```
uname -r
4.19.57-v7+
```

When I change my makefile to point to the 4.19.58-v7+ instead of 4.19.57-v7+, I get my module to build with no issues.

I'm expecting to see folders with 4.19.57 in their names, but all I get is 4.19.58 (see the folders above).  How can I get the Linux header files that match my Linux kernel version?  Or does it not matter?

Comment: Reboot your machine and choose new kernel in the boot loader. It seems you updated kernel without rebooting. Possible variants: distribution wrongly provided updates, update has been broken.

Comment: Debian/Raspbian's APT doesn't usually _automatically_ remove packages related to the _running_ kernel, although that doesn't prevent them being marked as obsolete packages. The mechanics of this are that the packages get listed in an `APT::NeverAutoRemove` section in the "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels" file, which is updated by the kernel postinstall script "/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal".

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, all I had to do was to reboot my Raspberry Pi after updating the OS.  Now it's at 4.19.58, and all the headers match the OS version and everything compiles just fine.